# How do I press and hold a key and have it repeat in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use the vim plugin and I typically scroll in vim by just holding j. In VSCode holding j just does a single j command, no matter how long it's held for.

Even in vanilla vscode this also doesn't work - problematic if you're trying to type long blocks of ########################### for comment separators. Any idea how to enable this functionality?

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned here in the official plugin documentation. https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#mac. I also did a mac restart and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 785, accepted):

To disable the Apple press and hold for VSCode only, run this command in a terminal:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Then restart VSCode.

To re-enable, run this command in a terminal:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

Comment: appreciate the "not affecting things globally" version you provided.

Comment: this does not work for me VSCode Version 1.31.1 (1.31.1), macOS 10.14.2.

Comment: Just want to chime in here if you're using the VSCode Insiders version, you should use: `defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

Comment: A useful variation is to give the `-app` flag instead of a domain, since the app name is easier to find than the domain, particularly for atypical builds of VSCode. I use the VSCodium build, so I was able to get the desired effect with `defaults write -app VSCodium ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

Comment: Can you explain what the `-bool false` bit does?

Comment: As stated in the answer, make sure you restart. Reloading the window doesn't put this into effect.

Comment: You can't just close the window, but should actually `quit` vscode before relaunching.

Comment: Even though the app is now called "Visual Studio Code" in Spotlight, the command above still works.

Comment: WOW, serious respect. How did you figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: I had to log out and then log on again for it to work.

Comment: If you use VSCode Insiders specify `com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders` instead of `com.microsoft.VSCode`

Comment: I had to log out of macOS and log back in before this setting took effect.

Answer (score 93):

You are on OSX, correct? If so, the issue might be Apple's "Press&Hold", where you can select alternative characters on long presses.

You can disable this "feature" with a defaults command in the terminal:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

You have to restart VSCode afterwards.

To reenable the previous behaviour:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

Comment: This worked for me.   The functionality was working fine for me in Atom, but not vscode.  Any reason why it should work in one and not the other?

Comment: You can disable it on a per application basis too, its possible that Atom ships this as default  (via `defaults write com.github.atom ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` or whatever the correct domain id is)

Answer (score 66):

The [official vim-plugin](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#mac-setup) for VS Code mentions how to set it up on macOS

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled  # If necessary, reset global default
```

Comment: `defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled` was what I was missing. It still retains the default behavior for the other apps. 

Comment: working, don't forget to re launch your vscode to get it work

Answer (score 19):

The answer by Steve above didn't quite work for me because of global settings. It also left me curious about where to find the `com.microsoft.VScode` domain name for an app. Here is what worked for me and a generalized formulation:

To enable repeats for a specific app, like VSCode, first make sure that there isn't an overriding global setting.

`defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled`

Then enable the setting for the specific app, you can find the domain name of an app by finding it in the `Info.plist` document under the Contents folder where it is installed.

Example

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.microsoft.VSCode</string>
```

Then set the setting on the command line.

`defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

You can use this pattern other app specific settings as well. Just make sure that your settings aren't being overwritten globally.

For more information on `defaults` type `defaults help`. One more note, you don't need to run this as `sudo` if your user is already an admin.

Comment: `make sure that there isn't an overriding global setting`

That's what did it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

**Operating System : Mac**

To enable key-repeating execute the following in your Terminal and restart VS Code:

```
$ defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false         # For VS Code
$ defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false # For VS Code Insider
$ defaults write com.visualstudio.code.oss ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false    # For VS Codium
$ defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled                                      # If necessary, reset global default
```

We also recommend increasing Key Repeat and Delay Until Repeat settings in System Preferences -> Keyboard.

this is all in our readme https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/README.md#mac-setup

Comment: The first line is the only solution that worked for me. OSX 12.3 and VS Code 1.67.2

Answer (score 10):

If you're on a mac and using VSCodium:

`defaults write com.visualstudio.code.oss ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

Other answers targeting `com.microsoft.VSCode` do not work because you're not running MS VSCode. The command `default write` generates/updates files in `~/Library/Preferences/` appended with `.plist`, you have to target the right file.

---

My software and versions:
macOS Mojave 10.14.6
VSCodium 1.41.1
 - Vim (by vscodevim) 1.12.4 with neovim enabled
Neovim 0.4.3
Vim 8.1.2250

Answer (score 8):

If on mac, you should refer to the extension's Mac-specific instructions: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#mac

At the moment (Aug 2022), it says:

> To enable key-repeating, execute the following in your Terminal, log out and back in, and then restart VS Code:
>
> ---
>
> For VS Code users:
>
> `defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`
>
> For VS Code Insider users:
>
> `defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`
>
> For VS Codium users:
>
> `defaults write com.visualstudio.code.oss ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`
>
> For VS Codium Exploration users:
>
> `defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeExploration ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`
>
> If necessary, reset global default:
>
> `defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled`
>
> ---
>
> We also recommend increasing Key Repeat and Delay Until Repeat settings in System Preferences -> Keyboard.

Comment: For VSCodium: defaults write com.vscodium ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/DOCS.md

Comment: The comand from the extension install section didn't worked for me, but this worked in OS X Ventura `defaults write -app VSCodium ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

Comment: line 2 worked for me after using cmd+Q on vscode (no relogin needed). The 5th line seemed to not work. Not sure what's it's supposed to do anyway

Comment: @Rivenfall the last line is to restore the default setting if necessary (see comment at the end of the line)

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me with my new laptop, instead I had to use:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Answer (score 3):

The best answer from Steve doesn't work for my mac 'defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false', however below works for me:

```
sudo defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

reference: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/345

Comment: full docs: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#mac

Answer (score 2):

For those of you on VS Code Insiders, just change the Bundle identifier to:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Comment: This works on M1 MacBook Air with insider. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For my M1 MacBook Pro, I had to run

```
sudo defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

as [noappleonhead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7947281/noappleonhead) said

Then had to restart/relogin Mac. And it started to work fine.

Comment: I am on M1 but I don't need to restart mac to take effect and I ran defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false instead since I use insider

Comment: I had to restart on M2, thanks for mentioning that step.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac M1 what I had to do was run what @NoAppleOnHead said of:

```
sudo defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Then after doing so restart your Mac and you should be good to go

Comment: I am on M1 but I don't need to restart mac to take effect and I ran `defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` instead since I use insider

Answer (score 0):

```
Though I reset with above mentioned commands and even after reboot, Once I open
VSCode they are getting reset, so I had 'code' script to set them back
every time I open VSCode editor.

 $ cat code
VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* &
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled
```