# How to make key repeat work on Vim for VsCode?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

The [top answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972335/how-do-i-press-and-hold-a-key-and-have-it-repeat-in-vscode) doesn't work for me.

I'm trying to navigate my file faster, but if I hold either `j` or `k` or any other vim navigation key it doesn't do the repeat command (it doesn't fly past words, it gets stuck)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That works for me. Please check the instructions below:

#### Mac

To enable key-repeating execute the following in your Terminal and restart VS Code:

```sh
$ defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false         # For VS Code
$ defaults write com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false # For VS Code Insider
$ defaults write com.visualstudio.code.oss ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false    # For VS Codium
$ defaults delete -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled                                      # If necessary, reset global default
```

We also recommend increasing Key Repeat and Delay Until Repeat settings in *System Preferences -> Keyboard*.

#### Windows

Like real vim, VSCodeVim will take over your control keys. This behaviour can be adjusted with the `useCtrlKeys` and `handleKeys` settings.

Comment: Thank you! This has been driving my crazy

Comment: For me it didn't work, I had to first type this defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
to enable key to be repeated using Mac