# How can I change the delay until a held keypress begins to repeat in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I'm using the VS Code Vim extension, and if I want to move down and I hold `j` for example it will move down once, pause then continue. Is there a way to make it automatically keep going up without that pause?

I've been digging through the settings and Google all morning and I can't see where I can or if I can changes this.

The closest I found to an answer was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972335/how-do-i-press-and-hold-a-key-and-have-it-repeat-in-vscode) but it did't really help (I am on windows sadly).

Comment: Firstly, `J` will most likely join your lines not scroll. You are looking at the `j` operator right? (I don't use vscode). But don't worry to much about your problem, you will learn better movement operators like `C-d` and `}`

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo yea I meant `j` sorry, I do use `C-d` but it always jumps a bit far that I intend when I want to hold `j`. I only want to use it to go down a handful of lines but spamming `j` is quite annoying and `3j` feels a bit uncomfortable at the moment as I have to mentally count the lines etc.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: is there a thing like `rnu` in vscode? (edit: yes, there is) that might help. I do not use `3j` often but I use `}` and search for specific stuff. but there is a ton of movement options in vim. `<linenumber>gg` can also be quite fast. There are plugins for indent based movements, code based movements etc. I hope someone with vscode experience can help you a bit better

Comment: Awesome, Thanks you this has been a massive help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this behaviour is controllable by VS Code or any VS Code extension. If I understand correctly, this behaviour is controlled / configured at the Operating System / Desktop Environment level.

- [For Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-repeat-keys.html.en): Settings > Accessibility > Repeat Keys > Delay
- For Windows: Keyboard Properties > Speed > Repeat Delay
- [For macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchl0311bdb4/mac): System Settings > Keyboard > Delay Until Repeat

Also note that in Vim, you can make a command execute multiple times by prefixing it with a number. Ex. To do `j` 42 times, just do `42j`. And to jump to line `N`, do `NG` (where `N` is the line number and `G` is the literal character `G`).

Comment: Thanks Muchly you are right I went into the systems and it fixed it. and yeah I do use `Nj` this was more for say a handful of lines if im bouncing around. @user

Comment: It's really helpful. thank you.